# "An error occurred submitting the edit." when updating a tag wiki edit from the revisions history

Tags: bug, edits, tag-wiki

Steps:

1. Collect 20,000 reputation to get the [Tag Wikis privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).
2. "<kbd>Edit Tag Info</kbd>" + "<kbd>Save Edits</kbd>" on a tag wiki info page.
3. In the following 5 minutes of your edit:

   4. Visit the "<kbd>history</kbd>" of the tag.
   5. "<kbd>edit</kbd>" from the tag revisions page.
   6. "<kbd>Save Edits</kbd>".

Results:

- "**An error occurred submitting the edit.**" systematically pop ups in red
- But at the same time, the edit *does actually succeed*. So using <kbd>Cancel</kbd> will bring you back to the previous page with all the changes applied.